# Cross the data in row data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel data in the form of below

`Name   N1
Prod    P1
Func    F1
Name    N2
Prod    P2
Func    F2
Name    N3
Prod    P3
Func    F3`

I would like to move this data in the format of

`Name Prod Func
N1   P1   F1
N2   P2   F2
N3   P3   F3`

I have tried index matching but that did not work. Could you please suggest a better way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enter the formula in cell `E2` as in image below,

```
=INDEX($B:$B,COLUMN(A:A)+((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))*3),1)
```

[image]

This should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For a long list the task may be easier and quicker without a formula. Simply copy the right hand column of data into two more columns and delete the top cell from the first copy and the top two from the second, in both cases with Shift Up. Then insert a header row and Copy/Paste Special/Values Transpose the first three elements of the left-hand column into it. Filter to select and delete rows starting `Prod` and `Func` then delete the left-hand column.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. this definitely helps since i am doing this in a long list. Another question i have is that what if the data is in non linear manner and the order in the columns is random(for eg. name prod and func are not added in linear manner). How would the data ordering and indexing work?